# How to hide single div at a time without flashing rather setting visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to hide a single `div` at a time so that **below flashing can be avoided(shown in image)**

[image]

**NOTE:** i cannot use `visibility:hidden` or `visibility:show`  or `$sel.css('visibility','hidden');` or `$sel.css('visibility','show');`

**My Expectation:**  when I do `$content.hide();` in the `DOM` see html area in image provided by me where `style="display:none"/style="display:block"` is happening  for every `element`,  rather I want to hide that  particular `element` at a time **(so no multiple display/hide at a time,  only one display/hide)**  similar to #snippet2, #snippet1 should work (but hidden element should not contain any `width/height`)

**below is my code which should work with `display:none or $el.hide()/$el.show()`:**

**#Snippet1**

```js
$(function() {
  var pos = 1;
  var ii = 0;

  var centerbandTop = $('.center-band').offset().top;
  var centerbandBottom = $('.center-band').outerHeight() + centerbandTop;
  $('.contents').hide();
  var intId = setInterval(function() {
    ii++;
    pos = -ii;
    //console.log(pos);
    //if (pos )
    $('.contents').each(function() {
      var $content = $(this);
      var contentTop = $content.offset().top;
      var contentBottom = $content.outerHeight() + contentTop;
      
     $content.hide();
      
      //console.log($content.position().top, centerbandTop, contentBottom);
      if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)
        $content.show();
    });

    $('.container').css({
      // '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + pos + ')',
      transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
    });

  }, 100);
});
```

```css
.container{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000d6;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #a19999;
    position: relative;
}

.contents{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.center-band{
    width: 98%;
    height: 78px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #b4b1b147;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.over{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contents"> (1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
      <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
      <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
      <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
      <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
      <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
      <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
      <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
      <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
      <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>

    </div>
    <div class="center-band"> </div>
  </div>
```

**Question: Above snippet(#snippet1) should work as same as below(#snippet2) one but without using `visibility`(#snippet2 Working without flashing)**

**#snippet2**

```js
$(function() {
  var pos = 1;
  var ii = 0;

  var centerbandTop = $('.center-band').offset().top;
  var centerbandBottom = $('.center-band').outerHeight() + centerbandTop;

  var intId = setInterval(function() {
    ii++;
    pos = -ii;
    //console.log(pos);
    //if (pos )
    $('.contents').each(function() {
      var $content = $(this);
      var contentTop = $content.offset().top;
      var contentBottom = $content.outerHeight() + contentTop;
      
      $content.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      
      //console.log($content.position().top, centerbandTop, contentBottom);
      if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)
        $content.css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

    $('.container').css({
      // '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + pos + ')',
      transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
    });

  }, 100);
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000d6;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #a19999;
    position: relative;
}

.contents{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.center-band{
    width: 98%;
    height: 78px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #b4b1b147;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.over{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contents"> (1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
      <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
      <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
      <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
      <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
      <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
      <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
      <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
      <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
      <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>

    </div>
    <div class="center-band"> </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you mean the part where devtools shows that something is changing in the dom? That's what you want to hide?

Comment: Why do you care about DevTools and it flashing its DOM changes?

Comment: In each interval run whole `div` hides expect one and the frequency is very fast.    **BUT**  I want to hide one one at a time, so no flashing occurs

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I think your question is still confusing. What exactly is the problem? What's not performing how you would expect? How do you expect it to perform?

Comment: I'd love to help but I dont understand what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the flashing? That's just a feature of Chrome DevTools and it happens when something changes, no matter how small or big the change is.

Comment: @Lennholm, when I do `$content.hide();` in the `DOM` see html area in image provided by me where `style="display:none"/style="display:block"` is happening  for every `element`,  rather I want to hide that  particular `element` at a time **(so no multiple display/hide at a time,  only one display/hide)**

Comment: please see my **My Expectation**

Comment: @Lennholm, `ALT + TAB` i use for daily basis that is not my concern, my concern is  `style="display:none"/style="display:block"` is happening for every `element` rather for single `element` , so **rendered page** `flashes`

Comment: _“but hidden element should not contain any width/height”_ ... The problem here is that your calculation: `if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)` is based on the element's translated dimension/position...

Comment: @IronGeek,this `(centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)` works fine but rendered page flashes due to this 2 lines `$content.hide()  and $content.show()`,  with below approach I'm able to solve this problem `$content.css('visibility', 'hidden') and $content.css('visibility', 'visible')` **BUT PROBLEM IS** `visibility(hidden, visible)`  acquires width and height that I want to avoid,  that is why I'm looking for `display:none` kind of solution.

Comment: See #snippet2 which works fine but acquire `width` and `height` that is why I want to hide with `display:none($content.hide())` kind of approach, **BUT** due to bad placement rendered page flashes

Comment: Put a `console.log(contentTop, contentBottom)` just before `if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)` and you'll notice that when you use `$content.hide()` the value of `contentTop` and `contentBottom` are relatively fixed (never changes). So they either stay hidden or toggled forever between hidden and shown (which causes the flashes)

Comment: @IronGeek, that might be the problem, then how to solve that ?

Comment: Well, you could explicitly set the `width` and `height` to `0` whenever `visibility` is set to `hidden`... `$content.css({ visibility: 'hidden', width: 0, height: 0 })`... But that would only solve the `width` and `height` problem, you still need to change the calculation logic to accomodate the changes...

Comment: @IronGeek, sorry I didn't notice your this comment correctly,  Put a console.log(contentTop, contentBottom) just before if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom) and you'll notice that when you use $content.hide() the value of contentTop and contentBottom are relatively fixed (never changes). **but my requirement is whichever content touches that gray band should be `shown` otherwise it has to be `hidden` holding no `width and height `.**

Comment: @IronGeek,  please help me regard above comment pertaining to problem.  Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want `display:block` or `display:none` to appear on your elements, then use a class. Instead of `$content.css('display','none')` use `$content.addClass('hide')` to hide the element, then `$content.removeClass('hide')` to show the element. You of course still have to define your `.hide` class as `.hide {display:none}`.

Comment: @JM-AHMS,i works but not smooth as `visibility:hidden/shown` it flashes out the screen as shown in above image,     I want my result as smooth as `visibility:hidden/shown` with `.hide { display : none;} ` but it is not happening please help me.

Comment: @skBangalore The above image just shows you hovering over the DOM. I think a lot of people are confused what you're trying to achieve. How should it work? Can you link to a website or another example that it is working on?

Comment: The act of hiding/showing the div is negating the logic which checks whether the div is hiding/showing.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to understand your question, but from the code snippets you provided it looks like you need to fundamentally rethink your approach.

Your code moves the "container" div up and then computes the positions of the contained elements, but the problem is that when you hide or show an element all the other elements move in response. So when "contents 1" gets above the center band and you hide it, it stops taking up space and "contents 2" moves to where "contents 1" was. However, since "contents 1" was above the center band, now "contents 2" is above the center band and you are going to hide that, too. And so in your code, as soon as "contents 1" gets above the center band, all the contents will be hidden.

There are many ways to handle this, and the best way for your situation will probably depend on details of what you are truly trying to accomplish and which are not clear from your question. Using CSS `overflow: hidden` is probably the most efficient and you do not really explain what is wrong with that solution.

Another option is to adjust the position of the container to compensate for hiding the element. You also have to have some way to figure out when to show items that enter the box, which you cannot do from their position, because they are hidden. This snippet is not ideal, and there are some glitches because of margins, but it shows the concept.

```js
$(function() {
  var pos = 0;
  var showNext = false;

  var centerbandTop = $('.center-band').offset().top;
  var centerbandBottom = $('.center-band').outerHeight() + centerbandTop;

  var scroll = function() {
    pos--; // move the list up one pixel

    $('.contents').each(function() {
      var $content = $(this);
      // If the previous "contents" moved up enough
      // to make room for this hidden element, show it.
      if (showNext) {
        $content.show();
        showNext = false;
      } else if ($content.is(':hidden')) // nothing to do
        return;

      // We have to wait until after we have shown 
      // the element to compute its position.
      var contentTop = $content.offset().top;
      var contentBottom = $content.outerHeight() + contentTop;


      if (contentBottom < centerbandTop) {
        // If the element has exited the top of the
        // band, hide it, and move the container
        // down to compensate for removing this 
        // element.
        pos = pos + $content.outerHeight(true);
        $content.hide();
      } else if (contentTop > centerbandBottom) {
        // If the element is below the band,
        // hide it. Really this only needs to
        // be done the first time through.
        $content.hide();
      }
      // If there is room in the center band
      // below this element, show the next one
      showNext = contentBottom < centerbandBottom;
      $('.container').css({
        transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
      });
    });


  }
  // We start with the contents "visibility: hidden"
  // and all the elements displayed so we do not 
  // see them but still can compute their positions.
  // One pass through scroll() then hides everything
  // that needs to be hidden.
  scroll();
  // Now we can make everthing visible
  $('.contents').css('visibility', 'visible');
  // And now we set up the scrolling timer
  var intId = setInterval(scroll, 100);

});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000d6;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #a19999;
  position: relative;
}

.contents {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
  padding: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.center-band {
  width: 98%;
  height: 78px;
  z-index: 200;
  background: #b4b1b147;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contents"> (1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
    <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
    <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
    <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
    <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
    <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
    <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
    <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
    <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>

  </div>
  <div class="center-band"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially calculate the vertical beginning/ending values of all divs and store this data independently. Make all divs visible (`display !== 'none'`)in the DOM very briefly, while using `opacity` to hide them, in order to calculate their heights (no way to calculate div height without attaching it to the DOM).

Also need to make all scrollable items `position: absolute` so that their removal doesn't reflow the items beneath them. This means javascript also needs to calculate `top` positions for items.

Then, whenever things change (whenever new items potentially need to be shown/hidden) check all independently stored position data against the position of the "hot zone" (the zone with which contact causes visibility).

```js
window.onload = () => {
  
  let positions = []; // Independently store positional data for text items
  
  // Keep references to some useful DOM elements
  let hotZone = document.getElementsByClassName('hot-zone')[0];
  let scroller = document.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0];
  let scrollerHeight = scroller.getElementsByClassName('height')[0];
  let items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  
  let totalHeight = 0; // We'll track total height of items as we go
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let { height } = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    items[i].style.top = `${Math.round(totalHeight)}px`;
    items[i].style.display = 'none';
    positions.push([ totalHeight, height ]);
    totalHeight += height;
  }
  
  // Make sure the scroller doesn't shrink when we remove its children
  scrollerHeight.style.height = `${Math.round(totalHeight)}px`;
  
  let reevaluate = () => {
    
    let hotRect = hotZone.getBoundingClientRect();
    let scrollRect = scroller.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let [ itemTop, itemHeight ] = positions[i];
      itemTop += scrollRect.top; // Make relative to scroller
      itemTop -= scroller.scrollTop; // Make relative to scroll amt
      
      let tooHigh = itemTop + itemHeight < hotRect.top;
      let tooLow = itemTop > hotRect.bottom;
      let disp = (tooHigh || tooLow) ? 'none' : 'block';
      if (disp !== items[i].style.display) items[i].style.display = disp;
    }
  };
  
  // Immediately call `reevaluate` to initially show items
  reevaluate();
  
  // Now everything is nice so make the scroller completely opaque
  document.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0].style.opacity = '1';
  
  // Setup listeners to call `reevaluate` when there's a possibility
  // new items need to show. E.g., the "hot zone" has moved, the items
  // have moved, scrolls have happened, etc.
  scroller.addEventListener('scroll', reevaluate);
  
};
```

```css
.contain {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.scroller {
  position: relative;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0; /* Initially invisible (to avoid 1-frame flicker) */
}
.scroller > .height {
  position: relative;
  width: 0; height: 0; /* Invisible; lends the scroller its height */
}
.scroller > .item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.hot-zone {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 30%;
  width: 100%; height: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="hot-zone"></div>
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="height"></div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Not too much here :)</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">THIS<br/>ONE<br/>IS<br/>REALLY<br/>QUITE<br/>LONG<br/>INDEED<br/>GOOD<br/>SIR</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you said in your comment that

> but my requirement is whichever content touches that gray band should
>   be shown otherwise it has to be hidden holding no width and height

From this I understand that you need a vertical text scroller. Why don't you use the gray band div as a container, with overflow hidden, and then scroll the content through it?

```js
    $(function() {
        var pos = 1;
        var ii = 0;

        var centerbandTop = $('.center-band').offset().top;
        var centerbandBottom = $('.center-band').outerHeight() + centerbandTop;
        //$('.contents').hide();
        var intId = setInterval(function() {
            ii++;
            pos = -ii;
            //console.log(pos);
            //if (pos )
            $('.contents').each(function() {
                var $content = $(this);
                var contentTop = $content.offset().top;
                var contentBottom = $content.outerHeight() + contentTop;

                //$content.hide();

                //console.log($content.position().top, centerbandTop, contentBottom);
                //if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)
                    //$content.show();
            });

            $('.container').css({
                // '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + pos + ')',
                transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
            });

        }, 100);
    });
```

```css
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        /*height: 100%;*/
        background: #000000d6;
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #a19999;
        position: relative;
    }

    .contents{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
        padding: 20px;

        /*visibility: hidden;*/
    }

    .center-band{
        width: 98%;
        height: 78px;
        z-index: 200;
        background: #b4b1b147;
        position: relative;
        /*top: 50%;*/
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .wrapper{
        position: relative;
    }

    .over{
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">

    <div>
        some static text above
    </div>
    <div class="center-band">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contents"> (1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
            <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
            <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
            <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
            <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
            <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
            <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
            <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
            <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
            <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        some static text below
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not my requirement , my requirement is whichever contents touches that band it has to be shown other has to be hidden(occupying no width and height)